# Android Studio: Load bitmap from file into canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I've create an Activity for draw a sign, save it into internal storage, reaload it and continue to draw starting from Bitmap saved.

At first launch the file is not loaded because it doesn't exists. So I draw and when I click back to previos Activity I save the Bitmap in file. From second launch the file exists and it is correctly loaded (I view image from debug in android studio). The problem is that the canvas appear blank. I have not Exception. Any ideas?

```
public class PhysicalSignatureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawingView dv ;
private Paint mPaint;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setTitle("Physical sign");

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    if (!(getIntent().getStringExtra("filename") == null)){
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().openFileInput(getIntent().getStringExtra("filename"));
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            Bitmap bitmap_mutable = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            dv = new DrawingView(this,bitmap_mutable);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

        }
    } else {
        dv = new DrawingView(this);
    }
    setContentView(dv);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setMessage("Save sign?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            String filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png";
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
            try {
                outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                dv.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = dv.getDrawingCache();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent i = new Intent(PhysicalSignatureActivity.this,  PerformanceActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("performance_id",getIntent().getStringExtra("performance_id"));
                i.putExtra("authentication_token",getIntent().getStringExtra("authentication_token"));
                i.putExtra("filename",filename);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public class DrawingView extends View {

    public int width;
    public  int height;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;
    private Paint circlePaint;
    private Path circlePath;

    public DrawingView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
    }

    public DrawingView(Context c, Bitmap b) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        mBitmap = b;
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap,0,0,mBitmapPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);
        canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        circlePath.reset();
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `(I view image from debug in android studio)`. What are you looking at? `Bitmap bitmap` or `Bitmap bitmap_mutable` ? You better check in code if they are null before use.

Comment: `catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

            }} } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } `. Even if you have exceptions you start a new Intent in the finally block. Of course you should not do that. Moreover you should place Toast()'s in the catch blocks to inform the user. And then return.

Comment: `} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

        }` Also place ex.printStackTrace(); in it and a Toast to inform the user. You do not know what is happening now!

Comment: `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`. Please give an example of such a filename. You let us guess now what you are doing.

Comment: @greenapps in response to your comments:
1) I'm looking the right Bitmap object.
2) I've adjusted catch but now it wasnt a problem, because Bitmap is saved and Loaded correctly, just not displayed in Canvas.
3) done
4) file name dbbe5e4a-d902-40b9-875d-0761e3ef2029.png